# get pandas categorical column categories and assign them as a dtype to another column

Tags: pandas

I'm creating an empty dataframe with a given shape and want to fill it with some values from another given dataframe that contains categorical columns, is it possible to share the same categorical dtype for the column in the new dataframe if it will have only a subset of original one's unique values?

Comment: DataFrames are heterogeneous. What you described is possible for Series and of course you can use those Series in different DataFrames but I think you should explain what you want on an example.

Comment: Basically, given a Series `ser1 = pd.Series(pd.Categorical(list('abcabc'), categories = list('cba'), ordered=True))`  You can generate another Series `ser2 = pd.Series(pd.Categorical(list('bb'), categories=ser1.cat.categories))` Now `ser2`  only contains `b` but its categories contain `c, b, a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use [Series.cat.remove_unused_categories()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cat.remove_unused_categories.html) method.

Here is a small demo:

```
In [311]: df
Out[311]:
    channel day month             t1    title  year
631     AAA  06    01  1388967300000  title 1  2014
632     CBR  06    01  1388973300000  title 2  2014
633     CBR  06    01  1388974500000  title 3  2014

In [312]: df.channel
Out[312]:
631    AAA
632    CBR
633    CBR
Name: channel, dtype: category
Categories (2, object): [AAA, CBR]

In [313]: cp = df[df.channel == 'CBR'].copy()

In [314]: cp.channel
Out[314]:
632    CBR
633    CBR
Name: channel, dtype: category
Categories (2, object): [AAA, CBR]

In [315]: cp.channel.cat.categories
Out[315]: Index(['AAA', 'CBR'], dtype='object')

In [316]: cp.channel.cat.remove_unused_categories(inplace=True)

In [317]: cp.channel.cat.categories
Out[317]: Index(['CBR'], dtype='object')

In [318]: cp.channel
Out[318]:
632    CBR
633    CBR
Name: channel, dtype: category
Categories (1, object): [CBR]
```

**UPDATE:**

```
In [328]: new = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2]})

In [329]: new['ch'] = df.loc[df.channel == 'CBR', 'channel'].values

In [330]: new
Out[330]:
   x   ch
0  1  CBR
1  2  CBR

In [331]: new.dtypes
Out[331]:
x        int64
ch    category
dtype: object

In [332]: new.ch.cat.categories
Out[332]: Index(['AAA', 'CBR'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: thank you. can I use cp.channel.cat as a dtype for a newly created another dataframe somehow? so that one of it's columns will become categorical with the same categories instead of object by default?

Comment: "I think you can use Series.cat.remove_unused_categories() method." No, in my case I want exactly the opposite of that

Comment: @AlexanderReshytko, in this case you don't need to call `Series.cat.remove_unused_categories()` - check UPDATE section in my answer